# How to POST data to my Rails 5.2 application API with Curl, with authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise

I recently had to upload data to my Rails application API using Curl. To make it short, I bypassed the **Devise** authentication for this specific API. But now it's time to enforce authentication, prior to deployment. This is just a question of adding an Authorization header to the request, isn't it?

I built the following header using login:password with Base64 encoding:

```
-H "Authorization:Basic QWRtaW46I1Byb3RvdHlwZTEzIQ=="
```

Unfortunately, I do not manage to implement Curl's authentication to Devise for posting to the API:

```
curl --noproxy localhost 
     -d @external_activities.json 
     -H "Authorization:Basic QWRtaW46I1Byb3RvdHlwZTEzIQ==" 
     -H "Content-type: application/json" 
     http://localhost/API/external_activities
```

The application returns the status `401 Unauthorized`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   -d '{"data1": "value1","data2":"value2"}'
   --user "login:password"` ref: https://reqbin.com/req/c-2cd3jxee/curl-post-with-basic-authentication-example

Comment: Yes, I did try this before building the authorization header (which is equivalent), it does not work either.

Comment: it may not be the issue with the CURL command, you might have to debug this with debugger inside the method

Comment: HTTP basic auth is not turned on by default in Devise. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication

Comment: Yes Max, you are right! I did not notice this important information ... Thanks a lot!!!